# PHP grab corresponding column id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have the following html/php table:

```
    <table id="blacklistgrid">
        <tr id="Row1">
            <td class="space">&nbsp;</td>
             <?php
        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT assignment,a_id FROM assignments WHERE groupid=0");
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo'<td class="columnname" id="'.$row['a_id'].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row['assignment'].'</td>';

        }
        ?>

      <script>
$('.columnname').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
        var text= $('.columnname').text();
        var id= $('.columnname').attr('id')
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"updateassignment.php",
            data:{text:text, id:id},
            success:function(data){
                console.log('success bro!');
            }
        });
    }, 500 );
});

var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
</script>     

        </tr>
        <?php
        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT name,memberid_fk FROM groupsort INNER JOIN members ON groupsort.memberid_fk=members.memberid WHERE group_id_fk=0");
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo' <tr id="Row2">';
           echo' <td>';
                echo'<h3>'.$row['name'].'</h3>';

             echo'</td>';
            $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT submitted FROM userassignment WHERE userid=".$row['memberid_fk']." and groupid=0");
            $row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            if ($row2['submitted']==0){
            echo' <td>';
                echo' <input type="checkbox" name="red" />';
            echo' </td>';

            }else if ($row2['submitted']==1) {
             echo' <td>';
                echo' <input type="checkbox" name="red" checked />';
            echo' </td>';   
            }
        echo' </tr>';

        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Im creating a system to keep track of who submits their homework, so it is in the form of a table. On the left side would be all the names of people (in the class), and the right are individual columns with the names of various assignments.

I am using contenteditable to update the name of the assignment/ and also checkboxes to tick when a student/person submits his assignment.

However, in order to make the tick work, what happens is i need to get the corresponding .columnclass id (which i have assigned as the assignmentid), for me to update the correct field.

The issue now is that the columnclass php is in the front while loop, so im not very sure how to access the column class id from the second php whileloop. **QUESTION: Is there a way for php to grab the id of the td(an element) without using javascript?**

If user submitted assignment, the submitted row in my table would be 1, so then php would display checked checkboxes. However, as per its mysql query, i need to add the assignment id as well, which can be retrieved from the ID of the corresponding td columnclass id.

The table looks something like this:

```
             Assignment 1           Assignment 2

Name1          CHECKBOX                CHECKBOX

Name2          CHECKBOX                CHECKBOX

Name3          CHECKBOX                CHECKBOX

Name4          CHECKBOX                CHECKBOX
```

So lets say i want to see if name1 submitted assignment1, then in my mysql table, i need to feed it both the userid AND the corresponding assignment id, therefore to retrieve the assignment id, i need to grab the id of the "assignment 1" .columnclass element's id (which i stored the value of assignmentid) I feel that this is a hack, is there a better way to do this?

[image: Sample table from my code. Note that i removed the add column/row code in my code snippet above to make it simpler]

Note i removed the add column/row code in the code snippet above to increase simplicity.

To make it even simpler to understand the table code above, the table is created like this:

```
(row 1)  emptytd1     td2(assignment)..
(row 2)    td1(name)  td2(checkbox)..
  .
  .
```

To determine if td2 should be checked, i need to query the database, and to do that, since there are multiple users and multiple assignments, i need the name and the assignment, the name is easy to get since  it is within the query, but the assignment is in the previous php while loop.

Comment: I expect I would query the database for completed assignments and create a simple PHP array, before writing the table. Something like "$assignments_completed[$user_id][$assignment_id] = 1;", then, when writing the checkboxes I can simply check for "isset($assignments_completed[$user_id][$assignment_id])".

Comment: sorry but im a beginner at arrays, really, i think the only way is definitely to use one query only but couldnt really think of a way to generate such a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, when you get to listing out the users in your table, you're not looping over the existing assignments. What you have only writes to the first assignment column, regardless of what assignment the user submitted.

So, below are a few tweaks of your existing code. First I added two lines to your assignments header row, marked with comments. The first creates an assignments array (for later use), and the second loads that array with the existing assignments.

Then, when looping over the users, for each user I added a loop over the existing assignments array. This accomplishes two things, 1) it puts aligns the assignments to the appropriate column, and 2) it gives you the assignment id you need to check if the user submitted the assignment. (I also used prepared statements for added security.)

**NOTE:** I'm guessing that your "userassignment" table has a field named "a_id" that gets set along with "userid" when a user submits an assignment.

```
<table id="blacklistgrid">
        <tr id="Row1">
            <td class="space">&nbsp;</td>
             <?php
        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT assignment,a_id FROM assignments WHERE groupid=0");
        $assignments = array(); // create empty assignments array
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo'<td class="columnname" id="'.$row['a_id'].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row['assignment'].'</td>';
            $assignments[$row['a_id']] = $row['assignment']; // add assignment to array
        }
        ?>

      <script>
$('.columnname').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
        var text= $('.columnname').text();
        var id= $('.columnname').attr('id')
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"updateassignment.php",
            data:{text:text, id:id},
            success:function(data){
                console.log('success bro!');
            }
        });
    }, 500 );
});

var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
</script>     

        </tr>
        <?php
        $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT name,memberid_fk FROM groupsort INNER JOIN members ON groupsort.memberid_fk=members.memberid WHERE group_id_fk=0");
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo' <tr id="Row2">';
            echo' <td>';
            echo'<h3>'.$row['name'].'</h3>';

            echo'</td>';

            // LOOP OVER ASSIGNMENTS ARRAY
            foreach ( $assignments as $a_id => $assignment ) {

                $query2=mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT submitted FROM userassignment WHERE userid=? and groupid=0 and a_id=?"); // added assignment id condition
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query2, "ii", $row['memberid_fk'], $a_id);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($query2);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query2, $submitted);
                mysqli_stmt_fetch($query2);

                $checked = ( $submitted )? 'checked': '';
                echo" <td> <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"red\" $checked /> </td>";

                mysqli_stmt_close($query2);
            } // end assignments array loop

            echo' </tr>';
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You are correct that my userassignment" table has a field named "a_id" set together with userid that references to the assignment table which contains the assignment info

Comment: Although now it returns me lots of Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /...testtable.php on line 99

Comment: i think because there are two same variables $query and $row

Comment: there are actually 3 $query, could that be causing all the "expect" errors

Comment: ah ha i got it partially working, corrected some errors, will update you

Comment: actually my "submitted" works like this, if it is listed as 1 in the database, then the checkbox should be checked, if it is null or doesnt exist, then it shouldnt be checked.

Comment: my userassignment table only contains values of users who have submitted assignments, whereas those who have not submitted are not there, therefore "submitted" could actually not exist

Comment: Nice call on the multiple "$query" variables. I updated the code.

Comment: Regarding "submitted", the tertiary statement checks to see if the variable $submitted has been set, if so, checks the checkbox, if not does not check the box. Is it not working that way?

Comment: ah i see, another question, do you think it is easier to use nested for loops to complete this?

Comment: it works now! one last question, if i want to run php whenever a user checks a checkbox, how do i retrieve the corresponding assignmentid?

Comment: Regarding "nested for loops" I'm not clear what you mean. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: ah actually since i was using ajax to detect the click in checkbox, i might as well just retrieve the id directly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68169/discussion-between-user4269367-and-bloodyknuckles).